# fsolve + pchip + max: not finding root

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, numerical-methods, solver

I am trying to find the roots of multiple equations over a grid (want the equations to be 0 evaluated at the points in the grid) and am stacking all the function values as a vector.

I was able to do this in Matlab, but I guess there is some nuance with python I'm missing. fsolve just returns the initial guess (no matter what it is).

EDIT: I have identified the root of the problem and created a [bug report](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19370) on github. It's the maximization arguments (mu terms). The terms are squared to turn them into smooth functions. But the code does better when they're removed for some reason (still isn't finding root). When the squared terms are there, it just keeps returning the initial guess

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import pchip, Akima1DInterpolator
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline as spline

def ap(x, alpha, beta, delta, r, w, kgrid, zgrid, piz):
    m = len(kgrid)
    pp1 = pchip(kgrid, x[:m])
    pp2 = pchip(kgrid,x[m:2*m])
    #pp1 = spline(kgrid, x[:m],k=3)
    #pp2 = spline(kgrid,x[m:2*m],k=3)
    res = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(m):
        kp1 = x[i]
        c = (1 + r - delta) * kgrid[i] + w * zgrid[0] - kp1
        kpp1 = pp1(kp1)
        cp1 = (1 + r - delta) * kp1 + w * zgrid[0] - kpp1
        kpp2 = pp2(kp1)
        cp2 = (1 + r - delta) * kp1 + w * zgrid[1] - kpp2
        mu1 = x[i + 2*m]
        res[i] = c**(-1) - max(mu1, 0)**2 - beta * (1 + r - delta) * (piz[0, 0] * cp1**(-1) + piz[0, 1] * cp2**(-1))
        kp2 = x[i + m]
        c = (1 + r - delta) * kgrid[i] + w * zgrid[1] - kp2
        kpp1 = pp1(kp2)
        cp1 = (1 + r - delta) * kp2 + w * zgrid[0] - kpp1
        kpp2 = pp2(kp2)
        cp2 = (1 + r - delta) * kp2 + w * zgrid[1] - kpp2
        mu2 = x[i + 3*m]
        res[i + m] = c**(-1) - max(mu2, 0)**2 - beta * (1 + r - delta) * (piz[1, 0] * cp1**(-1) + piz[1, 1] * cp2**(-1))
        res[i + 2*m] = max(-mu1, 0)**2 - kp1
        res[i + 3*m] = max(-mu2, 0)**2 - kp2
    return res
```

Is the function and the evaluation is

```
alpha = 0.36
beta = 0.99
delta = 0.025
zgrid = np.array([1.25, 0.75])
piz = np.array([[0.9, 0.1], [0.1, 0.9]])
m = 51
kgrid = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 2, 20), np.linspace(2.5, 25, 20), np.linspace(30, 200, 11)))
theta = 1.8  
r=.034
w = (1-alpha)*(r/alpha)**(alpha/(alpha-1))
x0 = np.zeros(4*m)
x0[:m] = kgrid
x0[m:2*m] = kgrid
x0[2*m:3*m] = -np.sqrt(kgrid)
x0[3*m:] = -np.sqrt(kgrid)

def to_solve(x):
    return ap(x, alpha, beta, delta, r, w, kgrid, zgrid, piz)

x, f = fsolve(to_solve, x0, full_output=True,xtol=1e-12)[:2]
```

Changing the tolerance didn't help. I also tried simplifying and writing like

```
data = alpha, beta, delta, r, w, kgrid, zgrid, piz

x = fsolve(ap,x0,args=data)
```

But it changed nothing. I looked a long time for something on this, searched github for files that used this combination of functions, but to no avail. Also to be clear, I know that this initial guess is not the solution (from Matlab and also the normed value of the function at the initial guess is ~.2). I think it must have something to do with the interpolation or some python nuance I'm missing (I've stared at this code for a while). Many thanks

Comment: I experimented with two other approaches: first, I tried the alternative solvers in [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root), none of which were better than hybr, the algorithm used by fsolve. Second, I tried scipy.optimize.minimize, reducing the number of return values to one using `np.sqrt(to_solve(x) ** 2).mean())`. This worked, but has the problem of being very slow.

Comment: I just tried this and got that the function is still returning the initial guess -- did you check if that was happening @NickODell ? In any event, thanks so much for your effort!

Comment: `scipy.optimize.root()` always returned the original guess. `scipy.optimize.minimize()` found other better solutions if I gave it enough iterations to think. Very slow, though.